# Count the number of words without white spaces

Tags: r, string, tm

I have the following string:

```
str1<-" india hit milestone electricity wind solar"
```

Number of words contained in it is:

```
>sapply(strsplit(str1, " "), length)
[1] 7
```

It is not true because we have a space at the beginning of `str1`. I tried to trim the white space but:

```
> stripWhitespace(str1) # by tm package
```

returns the same situation:

```
[1] " india hit milestone electricity wind solar"
```

Why?

Comment: Where is `stripWhitespace` defined? My first thought was for `trimws` to remove the leading (and trailing, if present) spaces. That would make `sapply(strsplit(trimws(str1), " "), length)` "6".

Comment: stripWhitespace is for use in documents in a corpus set up using the tm package, not for strings.  If you just have a string, use trimws as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the base function `trimws`

```
sapply(strsplit(trimws(str1), " "), length)
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\b\\w+\\b",str1))
```

such that

```
> lengths(gregexpr("\\b\\w+\\b",str1))
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `stringr::str_trim` and `stringr::str_split` like this:

```
length(stringr::str_split(stringr::str_trim(str1), pattern=" ", simplify=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(str1, '\\w+')
#[1] 6
```